# Getting a image url from html srcset using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get an image url from an html that has an img srcset using javascript. I am particularly interested in getting 2nd or 3rd image.

Example of srcset within html:

```
<img srcset=\"http:example.jpg 140w,http:example.jpg 160w,http:example.jpg 320w,http:example.jpg 480w,http:example.jpg 720w,http:example.jpg 1280w,http:example.jpg 1500w\" src=\"http:example.jpg\" alt=\"example\">
```

I can only use pure javascript.

Any help will be much appreciated as I've already spent hours trying to get this work and the only success I had so far is to get all of those links out of html.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried and how does it not work?

Comment: What is expected output exactly?

Comment: @Biffen This is not really "parsing" HTML. Regexes are actually both quicker and easier when it's just one item from similar HTML pages.

Comment: I am trying to get the 2nd or 3rd url from img srcset.  The expected output is http:example.jpg.

Answer (score -1):

Using `http:([^ ,]+)` will match "example.jpg" in several spots. You can iterate through your results to get the one you're looking for.

### Explanation

- `http:` finds the literal
- `[^ ,]+` finds multiple non-space, non-comma characters.
- Parenthesis creates a match.